# GMail-safe Mail Program with Local Archive?

Tags: windows, gmail

For many years, I have been using Forté Agent to access GMail via POP3. This is what Google considers a "less safe" application, and as of the end of May 2022, it will no longer be possible to access GMail with this type of application. I am looking for a mail application that runs on Windows 7 and later that meets the following criteria:

1. Supports "Sign in with Google" or OAUTH2.
2. Creates a local copy of all mail. Optionally (and configurably), deletes it from GMail but not the local store when it makes a copy of mail not already in the local store.
3. Allows sorting of mail into different folders, both manually and by rule.
4. Can import and export between the local store and MBOX format. This would be met by a program whose local store is inherently in MBOX format.
5. Ideally, has built-in trainable spam recognition.

Gratis-without-adware is preferred, commercial is acceptable if not subscription and under US$50.

Comment: Thunderbird supports Oauth2 authentication, at least using IMAP, not sure about POP3.

Comment: I think POP3 is going away entirely from GMail, but if TB supports connecting via IMAP and still autocopying the mail to local store and save/export as MBOX, it'll meet my needs.

Comment: The GMail help still mentions `pop.gmail.com:995` (SSL) without any notice that this service ends in the near future.

Comment: Even though GMail is removing the "less safe" option, it would still be possible to normal POP3 clients to connect, by using an application password (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en). It forces you to use a two-factor authentication, though, but allows continued use of mail clients though the deadline.

Comment: @Alejandro - Google 2FA appears to require giving them a mobile number, which I'm not willing to do, as it would effectively link two accounts that I deliberately keep separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) meets points 1, 2, and 3 adequately; it requires an addon to meet point 4 (and the addon that I found doesn't seem to like the MBOX files that are generated by Forté Agent, my current email reader for everything except GMail). I have not yet found an add-on for point 5.

It *does* support OAUTH2 authentication when using POP3.